# Repeat texture in libgdx

Tags: textures, tiles, rendering, libgdx, spritebatch

How to fill region with repeated texture? Now I'm using next method:

```
spriteBatch.begin();

final int tWidth = texture.getWidth();
final int tHeight = texture.getHeight();

for (int i = 0; i < regionWidth / tWidth; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < regionHeight / tHeight; k++) {
        spriteBatch.draw(texture, i*tWidth, k);
    }
}

spriteBatch.end();
```

It's very obvious. Maybe is there any built in method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to set the texture's `TextureWrap` setting to `Repeat`. See [the documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.TextureWrap.html) for more information, and the [texture method](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/GLTexture.html#setWrap-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureWrap-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureWrap-).

Specifically:

```
setWrap(Repeat, Repeat);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use "SetWrap" on your texture and create a TextureRegion based on that Texture.
To Create a 3x3 mirrored image (or axb size)

```
Texture imgTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
imgTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat, Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat);
TextureRegion imgTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(imgTexture);
imgTextureRegion.setRegion(0,0,imgTexture.getWidth()*3,imgTexture.getHeight()*3);
```

**Important:** It took me a while to figure it out, but to be mirrored, your texture must be a power of two size. It was working on Android but not on iOS and you don't get a message - it was shown as black. So it must be 4x4 or 8x8, 16x16 .. 256x256 or 512x512 ..

Will give you this:
[image]

Below you can see the sample code that generated that picture using a Stage and Image Actor (Scene2D)

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    MyGdxGame game;
    private Stage stage;

    public GameScreen(MyGdxGame aGame){
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        game = aGame;
        Texture imgTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
        imgTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat, Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat);
        TextureRegion imgTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(imgTexture);
        imgTextureRegion.setRegion(0,0,imgTexture.getWidth()*3,imgTexture.getHeight()*3);

        TextureRegionDrawable imgTextureRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(imgTextureRegion);
        Image img = new Image();
        img.setDrawable(imgTextureRegionDrawable);
        img.setSize(imgTexture.getWidth()*3,imgTexture.getHeight()*3);
        stage.addActor(img);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```